# Custom URL in Meteor

Tags: javascript, url, meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I have url in my project like this: `https://localhost:3000/groups/KhHB9TwzZxiddgJND/event`

I want to get somethink like that: `https://localhost:3000/groups/groupName/event`

How can I do it? I use Meteor 1.3 on Blaze, flow-router for routing

Answer (score 0):

You would just define your route and use a `name` variable instead of an `id`:

```
FlowRouter.route('/groups/:name/event', {});
```

Then later when you wanted to set the data context for your template you would do something like:

```
let groupName = FlowRouter.getParam("name");
const group = Groups.findOne({ name: groupName });
```

An `_id` isn't special in a route, a route parameter is just something that you're eventually going to search by. The nice thing about an `_id` is that it's guaranteed unique. If you're searching by name then you may have to enforce uniqueness in your model unless you really want a list.

Comment: It works, but how can I get ' ' in URL ? I get this: `http://localhost:3000/groups/My%40Group/event` and want this: `http://localhost:3000/groups/My_Group/event`. No symbol codes in URL. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try decodeURI? https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/decodeURI